# Android - Custom views can bind to their own listeners by not specifying an ID - doesn't work

Tags: android, butterknife

I follow [butterknife instruction](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), as they said: "Custom views can bind to their own listeners by not specifying an ID."

Grade

```
Gradle 
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
```

I create a BaseButton:

```
public class BaseButton extends Button {

public BaseButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public BaseButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@OnClick
public void onClick() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.BaseButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"/>
```

And MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

//    @OnClick(R.id.button)
//    public void buttonPressed(){
//        System.out.println("buttonPressed");
//    }
}
```

If I un-comment buttonPressed method, "buttonPressed" shows up. When I comment, nothing happens. What I expect is to see "hello" first and then "buttonPressed".

Do you have any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's two problems here:

1. The view never calls `ButterKnife.bind(this)` to bind the click listener to itself. Without this, there's no way of knowing when to attach the listener. The call in the your activity does not implicitly bind the view to itself.
2. If you put an `@OnClick` for the button in your activity *and* an `@OnClick` for the button inside of itself one of them is going to overwrite the other. Butter Knife is just creating a click listener and calling `setOnClickListener` on the view. Since you'd have two, one will simply replace the other and you'll stop seeing the log line for whichever called `bind` first.

Comment: Thanks Jake, what if I would like add an action for all buttons before doing specific tasks. As usual, I can Override and call super, is it possible to make it with butter knife.

Comment: Override the click listener setter and wrap it with one that does your action before calling through.

Comment: Could you explain more how to override the click listener setter. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I too am working on a similar case, any suggestions here on how to override the click listener setter while using ButterKnife? Thanks